# Filter data frame based on condition pandas (string split)

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame as shown below

```
Prop_ID    Unit_ID      Prop_Usage      Unit_Usage
1          1            Res             Res
1          2            Res             Com
1          3            Res             Ind
1          4            Res             Res
2          1            Com             Res
2          2            Com             Com
2          3            Com             Com
3          1            Ind             Ind
3          2            Ind             Com
4          1            Res - Com       Res
4          2            Res - Com       Com
4          3            Res - Com       Ind
5          1            Com - Res       Res
5          2            Com - Res       Com
5          3            Com - Res       Ind
5          4            Com - Res       Com
```

From the above it is clear that one property may have more than 1 units. That means units are the subcategory of properties.

From the above data I want to filter rows where Prop_Usage does not match with Unit_Usage. We have a category in Prop_Usage column that Res - Com then Unit_Usage then the unit usage can be either of Res or Com.

Expected Output:

```
Prop_ID    Unit_ID      Prop_Usage      Unit_Usage
1          2            Res             Com
1          3            Res             Ind
2          1            Com             Res
3          2            Ind             Com
4          3            Res - Com       Ind
5          3            Com - Res       Ind
```

Comment: @jezrael please look into this question if you have time

Comment: @CodeDifferent that does not provide the expected out put?

Comment: It won't include the rows where Prop_Usage has multiple 'units'. See my answer below.

Comment: @user6745154 I realized that. See my full answer below

Comment: Seems over engineered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your dataframe is small enough that performance is not a concern:

```
mask = df[['Prop_Usage', 'Unit_Usage']] \
        .assign(
            Prop_Usage=lambda x: x['Prop_Usage'].str.split(' - ').apply(set),
            Selected=lambda x: ~x.apply(lambda row: row['Unit_Usage'] in row['Prop_Usage'], axis=1)
        )

df.loc[mask['Selected']]
```

What it does:

- Copy the `Prop_Usage` and `Unit_Usage` into a new dataframe
- Replace the `Prop_Usage` column with a split version of itself. Each row in the "after" version is a set of units

For example:

```
Prop_Usage             Prop_Usage
(before)               (after)
----------             ----------
Res                    {Res}
Res - Com        -->   {Res, Com}
Com - Res - Com        {Com, Res}
```

- Test if `Unit_Usage` is in the set, row-wise. If it is not, mark `Selected = True`
- Filter the original dataframe where `Selected` is True

Note that since it uses `.apply(..., axis=1)`, performance is not going to be great for larger dataframes.

Answer (score -1):

Pandas can directly compare columns row by row with:

```
df[~df.apply(lambda x: x.Unit_Usage in x.Prop_Usage, axis=1)]
```

Applying the lambda function will compare the strings in each rows and see if what is in Unit_usage is in Prop_Usage for that row and produce a boolean series. You can use this boolean series to slice the dataframe.